# How to access objects inside vue.js methods?

Tags: vuejs2, twig

I have a `json` array full of objects, inside my `vue` script, like this:

```
methods:{
 getProjects: function(){
    this.projects = JSON.parse('[{"cluster": "Demo", "name":"Joe", "id": 5454, "percentage": 100, etc}]');
  },
},
```

And now, I'd like to access those values in my `twig`, like I was doing with `angularjs`, for example:

```
<h5>{{ cluster.name }}</h5>
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put it into data() method

```
<script>
export default {
  data() => ({
    cluster: []
  }),
  methods: {
    getProjects() {
      this.cluster = '...';
    }  
}
}
</script>
```

in the template, you can only access the "data" or "computed" properties. And the property must be declared in data before you assign.
It's necessary because the Vue will create an observer on these properties to handle changes and update the DOM.